# DropDownList problem/doubt

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have one dropdownlist like this bellow.. the problem is that if I have more than 30 ListItem the list will have 30 elements/rows display and the rest to scroll. Is there a way to show only 10 elements and scroll the rest? I read in some pages that this is not possible. Is that true?

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="id" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="AA" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="AA" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
                 .                     
                 .
                 .
            <asp:ListItem Text="D" Value="AA" Enabled="true"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

The browser decides how many elements get displayed, not your code. So it's not possible. Your only way around it it to use a [Select Box Replacement](http://www.brainfault.com/2007/07/23/select-box-replacement/). Then you can completely control the appearance and not rely on the browser's default.